# Can I change the resize zones on windows in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, ui

It feels like the "hit zone" for the resize handle on windows in Yosemite is about 4 pixels wide. Meaning when I want to resize something I end up hunting around for it for 3 or 4 seconds every time. Is there a way to change this activation zone? I'd rather not have to install a tool to fix it.

Comment: I'm sure they're getting smaller with every OS - either that or I'm getting older ;) On El Cap I find that the actual point at which you get the helper arrows is one pixel, though it still works outside that zone, even with no indicator [sort of]

Comment: Hah I know what you mean; I think the pixel  density is going up but the zones are staying the same size -- so the real-world distance is getting tinier all the time.

Comment: If you mean the small green button in the top, you don't have to hunt for it. You can just click it if the mouse is hovering over it.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about @FlareCat, a resize handle is the part of the window border you use to resize the window

Comment: @jcollum Ohh, ok. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a GIF showing the border for resizing a window. It's not that small, but I don't think there's a way to change it.

[image: Border for window resizing GIF]